# How does rpmbuild compute which fields to generate?

Tags: cmake, rpm, rpmbuild, cpack

When comparing different RPM files, I've noticed that not all of them expose the same header tags. So there must be some logic that activates/deactivates creation of some of them.

One example is the build time and host. I've stumbled upon two RPM specs. Neither mentions anything that looks at all like a specification or switch to provide the information. Still, one of them is generated with `Build Time` and `Build Host` fields, the other isn't (I am not permitted to post either one).

I am aware of the new `_buildhost` macro. The RPM version used to generate both is insufficient to use it. Both packages get created from a list of Sources, as far as I can see. The one that doesn't display the build information gets built using CMake/CPack, the other uses `rpmbuild` directly, that's the only information I have about serious difference.

Both are defined as `Group: AddOn`. So far, I haven't found any remotely definite resources about what groups are valid, or their meanings. Only thing I found was the [list of *deprecated*](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/RPMGroups) groups in Fedora. I'd be more interested in a list of supported ones, but wasn't successful so far.

Resources I've found until now (omitting the pointless ones):
[Max RPM Package Building Page](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-rw-build-package-building.html), [RedHat blog-ish tutorial](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/create-rpm-package), [The RPM build guide](https://rpm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rpm-guide.html), [The actual RPM tags documentation](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-tags.html), [The RPM packaging guide](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/)

Unfortunately, none of the above provide the information I'm looking for.

**"Give a man a fish" question:** How can I suppress creation of `Build Time` or `Build Host` in `rpm` 4.11, be it in spec syntax or in usage of `rpmbuild`?

**"Teach a man how to fish" question:** Is there any documentation about what header tags get created with which settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mock](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki) for building rpm (recommended anyway). and use `config_opts['hostname'] = 'my.own.hostname'`.
Mock will call `sethostname()` in the chroot.
This is the only way how to do it AFAIK.

rpmbuild should honor [`SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH`](https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/source-date-epoch/) - but I never used it.
You can set environment variable using:
`config_opts['environment']['SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH'] = 'foo'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with vanilla Fedora packages. This also includes the limitation to rpm 4.11, which doesn't support `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` yet. According to the link in your reply, it is only supported as of rpm 4.13.

Comment: That must be very old Fedora. Even RHEL8.0 has rpm 4.14. All recent Fedoras has a newer version.

Comment: that may be so, but it doesn't change the constraints. Do you know of any way the selection of fields can be influenced for that version, or is it really only version-dependent?

Comment: Try this? https://github.com/AaronDMarasco/rpm-cookbook#spoofing-rpm-host-name